# Redraw/Refresh WMS layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have a WMS layer in my leaflet map:

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/volonteri/wms?', {
            layers: "trgovine",
            transparent: true,
            format: 'image/png'
        }).addTo(map);
```

In backend, there is a simple PHP script that stores new points into PostGIS table which is served via geoserver as WMS.

I use an AJAX request to send data to backend PHP script. I need to refresh the layer after successful insert to draw the new point on map, but cannot find any method for refreshing. The code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/trgovina',
        data: { 
            'name': name,
            'shop': shop,
            'geom': geometry
        },
        success: function(){
            /* Redraw/refresh/reload should go here */
        }
    });
```

How can I solve this? I remember the older versions of openlayers had something simple like .redraw() method, but I'm pretty new to leaflet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me quote from the Leaflet API documentation, about [methods for `L.TileLayer.WMS`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tilelayer-wms-setparams):

> `setParams(<Object> params, <Boolean> noRedraw?)`
>
> Merges an object with the new parameters and re-requests tiles on the current screen (unless `noRedraw` was set to true).

After this moment of RTFM, you should try to simply

```
wmsLayer.setParams({});
```

or even

```
wmsLayer.setParams({}, false);
```

---

That makes *Leaflet* tell the browser to re-request the tiles. But if the tile URLs are actually the same, your *web browser* might pull the tiles from its cache instead of re-requesting the tiles to the WMS server.

If this is the case, you might want to use some form of [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params), e.g. adding an ever-changing fake WMS parameter:

wmsLayer.setParams({ wmsParameterThatDoesntExist: Date.now() }, false);

If you do implement cache busting, be aware that this can negatively affect performance, specially if you expect lots of concurrent clients.

Comment: I tried `wmsLayer.setParams({}, false);` , but it doesn't work. New point is not visible in current zoom level (it is visible only after i zoom in or out). I also tried refrencing the wms layer in map object like this: `map._layers[33].setParams({}, false);`, but i get the same result. Seems like the tile is cached locally because i disabled caching in geoserver for that layer. Any way to work around this?

Comment: Look at the network requests that your browser is making. You might be pulling from the browser's cache. If that's happening, you might want to use some form of [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params), maybe via adding a ever-changing parameter (e.g. `setParams({fake: Date.now()})`).
If you do so, be aware of the performance implications of cache busting, specially if you expect lots of concurrent clients.

Comment: Works with cache busting `wmsLayer.setParams({fake: Date.now()}, false);`. Thanks. Can you expand your answer with this info so i can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Can't find this method on Leaflet documentation. Is it deprecated?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms-setparams

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be

```
Util.setOptions(<your_layer>, {})
```

`Util` comes from leaflet library; <your_layer> it the layer (in your case a WMS layer) you want to update; `{}` is the object that contains the properties you want to change.